# How to manipulate these constraints for 2-phase simplex method?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, two-phase-simplex

I am trying to solve an LP problem with 3 constraints:  $$x_1 + 2x_2 ≥6\\2x_1+x_2≥6\\ x_1 + x_2≤6\\$$ I understand that I need to change these constraints into standard from and add slack variables as well as another variable to make them equalities. However, I'm not sure what variables I should add to which constraints so that I can compute a feasible starting dictionary. One of my attempts was:  $$\\-x_1-2x_2+x_3-x_0=-6\\-2x_1-x_2+x_4-x_0=-6\\x_1+x_2+x_5-x_0=6\\$$ Where $-x_0$ is being maximized and $x_3,x_4,x_5,x_0$ are variables that I've introduced in an attempt to make the constraints feasible.$$$$I tried to continue with the 2-phase method from here but I couldn't find get a correct optimal solution so I'm assuming I haven't manipulated the constraints correctly. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Assuming slack variables are meant to be nonnegative, you have the wrong sign on $x3$ and $x_4$. Also, there is no need for $x_0$ to appear in the constraints.

Comment: Where is the objective function?

Comment: @Math1000 Those signs are correct because the original two constraints have been multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: @RobPratt So are the equalities I made here are correct?

Comment: @RobPratt I was a bit tired yesterday and managed to visually transpose the negative signs from the $x_0$ in those equations...indeed you are correct. (And again, the $x_0$ serve no purpose here.)